# Why do we need an Object parameter for equals method?

Tags: java, oop

I was making some tests with the java equals method and I figured out that if my parameter is not of the generic type Object the test won’t pass, even if the two objects I create are of that type. Let’s say I want to check if an object is an animal, what I tried to do is writing down:

```
 public boolean equals(Animal other) {
 *some code*
}
```

And then I create a test for that method to compare the animals. But if I do that the test will fail, on the other side, if I write down:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
 *some code*
}
```

and then test it, the test will pass. I understand that’s useless declaring the object of the desired type and try to test it but I don’t get why it doesn’t work in a good weather test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple, Object class `equals` method signature is this

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

But if you write `equals` method with `Animal` parameter then it will not be the `Overridden` equals method from object class. and when you try to compare objects by using `.equals()` Object class equals will be invoked

For this reason and to make it clear it is always recommended to use `@Override` annotation

Answer (score 2):

The `equals` method is part of the base `Object` class in Java and the only way to make benefit of it is to *override* it. To override it you need to stick to the same signature which will tell any libraries using `equals` to invoke your method instead of the base one.

Your above code is doing an *overloading* which is a totally different method to the Java compiler.